# Considering the composite map $R\to R/(p) \to \kappa(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. I have read that we can consider $f\in R$ as a function on the prime ideals of $R$, by defining $f(p)$ to be the image of $f$ under the composite map:

$$R\to R/(p) \to \kappa(p)$$

So the first thing I should do is, understand $\kappa(p)$. Say that $R=K[x,y]$, then we can consider $f(x)$ where we first map $f\mapsto f \text{mod} (x)$ and then we want to map into the fraction field.

Am I correct in thinking that:
$$\kappa(x) = \text{Quot}(K[x,y]/(x))\cong \text{Quot}(K[y])=K[y,y^{-1}].$$

Where if that is correct, I can see that, say $f= x^2+x+y^3$ has $f(x)$ given:
$$x^2+x+y^3\mapsto y^3\mapsto y^3.$$

To be honest, I have no idea what I am meant to see happen in the second map. I can't see what it could possibly do to my element.

Comment: The second map is just the inclusion of a domain into its fraction field. It is the identity on elements of the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $R/p\to\kappa(p)$ doesn't "do" anything, because it's injective and can therefore be thought of as an inclusion.

Also, $\text{Quot}(K[y])$ isn't $K[y,y^{-1}]$, it's $K(y)$.  So in this case, the map is $K[y] \subset K(y)$.

Comment: Why do we care about the second map? (Scheme theoretically)

Comment: I mean to ask, why do we consider $f(p)$ to be the image of $f$ under the composite map, whereas we could simply consider it as the image of $f$ under the first map?

Comment: There are lots of reasons.  One is that if a regular function is nonzero at a point, we want it to be invertible in a neighborhood of that point, so in particular it should take values in a field.  In general, the point of doing this is to use field theory to do geometry.  In your example, we can see that $\{(x,y) \mid x=0\}$, the zero set of $(x)$, is a variety of dimension $1$, because the residue field $\kappa((x))=K(y)$ has transcendence degree $1$ over $K$.

Comment: Really, it's just conceptually much easier to talk about functions taking values in general fields, which are pretty simple, rather than general integral domains, which are not.

Comment: On further consideration, I think that the primary reason is that we don't just want to look at functions on a scheme $X$, we want to look at functions on open subsets $U\subset X$.  If we don't pass to the field of fractions, the target of these functions will depend on $U$, which is not desirable.

Comment: Thank you for these comments (especially that last one!)